# Why does my apple developer not have button for adding new application?

Tags: app-store-connect

After I sign in to itunes connect, I don't see the plus symbol for adding a new app.

Look on my image for details.

Can anyone help, please feel free to show me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not test it but you may try to change your browser .
Or check your apple developer account it have a valid certificate and bundle id to add app on itunesconnect.

double check that you have accept all license agreements on itunesconnect.
[image: One more thing]